# how to move java server to web host and run it?

Tags: java, web, host

I have fully working localhost website(with java server, react front, MySQL database).I already moved front on host, but I can not understand or find how to move java server on web host and run it. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Do you mean how to deploy a java artifact(war/jar) on server?

Comment: yes, exactly that and plus how I should upload server files, just make zip and extract?

Comment: is it a web application using tomcat or standalone java application?

Comment: it is web site, on localhost it is worked on tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a war file of the java application using maven plugin and install tomcat on the host and then just copy the war file into the tomcat directory on the host. Here is [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war) on this.

Comment: do you have any tutorial video link?